# Find matching substrings in two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, string-matching

I have two dataframes like so:

```
[in]print(training_df.head(n=10))

[out]
                          product_id
transaction_id                      
0000001                   [P06, P09]
0000002         [P01, P05, P06, P09]
0000003                   [P01, P06]
0000004                   [P01, P09]
0000005                   [P06, P09]
0000006                   [P02, P09]
0000007         [P01, P06, P09, P10]
0000008                   [P03, P05]
0000009                   [P03, P09]
0000010         [P03, P05, P06, P09]

[in]print(testing_df.head(n=10))

[out]
                     product_id
transaction_id                 
001                       [P01]
002                  [P01, P02]
003             [P01, P02, P09]
004                  [P01, P03]
005             [P01, P03, P05]
006             [P01, P03, P07]
007             [P01, P03, P08]
008                  [P01, P04]
009             [P01, P04, P05]
010             [P01, P04, P08]
```

Each line in the testing_df is a possible "substring" of a line in the training_df. I would like to find all matches and return the possible training_df lists for each list in the testing_df. It would be helpful if I could return a dictionary where the keys are the transaction_id from the testing_df and the values are all possible "matches" in the training_df. (Each list in the training_df should be one value longer than the corresponding list in the test_df).

I tried:

```
# Find the substrings that match
matches = []

for string in training_df:
    results = []
    for substring in testing_df:
        if substring in string:
            results.append(substring)
    if results:
        matches.append(results)
```

However this doesnt work, it only returns the column name 'product_id'.

I also tried:

```
# Initialize a list to store the matches between incomplete testing_df and training_df
matches = {}

# Compare the "incomplete" testing lists to the training set
for line in testing_df.product_id:
    for line in training_df.product_id:
        if line in testing_df.product_id in line in training_df.product_id:
            matches[line] = training_df[training_df.product_id.str.contains(line)]
```

However this throws an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: I think the problem is the brackets. For example, "P01" is a substring of "[P01, P06]" but "[P01]" is not. You could try substring[1:-1] instead of substring in order to get rid of the brackets.

Comment: @csander I tried `matches = []

for string in training_df[1:-1]:
    results = []
    for substring in testing_df[1:-1]:
        if substring in string:
            results.append(substring)
    if results:
        matches.append(results)` but that didnt work either

Comment: No, you don't want to slice the DataFrame, you want to slice the substring

Comment: Still only returning the column name `[['product_id']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the brackets. The problem is that `in` checks whether an element is in a list, not whether one list is a subset of another. You can convert the two lists to sets and then check whether they are subsets of each other. You can also use advanced indexing to preserve the `transaction_id`:

```
training_df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['0000001', ['P06', 'P09']],
    ['0000002', ['P01', 'P05', 'P06', 'P09']],
    ['0000003', ['P01', 'P06']],
    ['0000004', ['P01', 'P09']],
    ['0000005', ['P06', 'P09']],
    ['0000006', ['P02', 'P09']],
    ['0000007', ['P01', 'P06', 'P09', 'P10']],
    ['0000008', ['P03', 'P05']],
    ['0000009', ['P03', 'P09']],
    ['0000010', ['P03', 'P05', 'P06', 'P09']],
], columns=['transaction_id', 'product_id'])

testing_df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['001', ['P01']],
    ['002', ['P01', 'P02']],
    ['003', ['P01', 'P02', 'P09']],
    ['004', ['P01', 'P03']],
    ['005', ['P01', 'P03', 'P05']],
    ['006', ['P01', 'P03', 'P07']],
    ['007', ['P01', 'P03', 'P08']],
    ['008', ['P01', 'P04']],
    ['009', ['P01', 'P04', 'P05']],
    ['010', ['P01', 'P04', 'P08']],
], columns=['transaction_id', 'product_id'])

matches = {}
for testing_id in testing_df.product_id:
    testing_id_set = set(testing_id)
    contains_id = training_df.product_id.apply(lambda id: testing_id_set.issubset(set(id)))
    matches[str(testing_id)] = contains_id
```

Comment: The testing_df and training_df are already formatted as pandas dataframes. When I try `matches = {}
for testing_id in testing_df.product_id:
    matches[testing_id] = training_df[training_df.product_id.str.contains(testing_id[1:-1])]` it simply returns an empty dictionary

Comment: I included the definitions to show the data I was testing with. If it isn't working for you, what do your data frames look like?

Comment: The brackets are on the outside so for example row 1, transaction_id 001, the product_id column is as follows: `['P01','P02','P03']`

Comment: Okay, I have updated the answer to take that into account

Comment: I will try this but please look at this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486506/algorithm-to-compare-dataframe-and-dictionary-and-return-missing-value-for-subst) I have updated the problem slightly

Comment: I was wrong, it works- but is very slowly. Moreover,  it keeps killing my kernel.